Add line to ruby file using a parser
I'm trying to add a healthcheck to a Rails 6 application container.
https://blog.saeloun.com/2023/02/27/rails-introduces-default-health-check-controller/#before
How can I add the line get '/health_check', to: 'health_check#show' to the config/routes.rb file programmatically (I can't just append it to the file), so probably using https://github.com/whitequark/parser
I couldn't make sense of this post but it looks promising
https://lethain.com/refactoring-programmatically/
Of course I could copy out the config/routes.rb file, edit it, and stick it back in, but I'd like to build this thing dynamically in docker.

How do you want to make this work? With bash from some Docker related file? Or with Ruby once your application is running?

Ideally already in the dockerfile

Why do you need to add this line to the file? Why not just call Rails.application.routes.draw and add the route that way? If that doesn't work why is just appending it to the file not an acceptable solution? Can you possibly clarify the use case?

Why do I need a use case? I'm asking a question not submitting a change request. If there's a way to call rails to add that route then pls show me how. Appending to the file places the line after the final end directive - how can this work?

@caduceus  Rails.application.routes.draw { get '/health_check', to: 'health_check#show'} just like it would be in routes.rb. Also you can write to a file in any location. The use case request was simply because there may be better ways to handle your request if we understood why. If you want to just go about it based on what you have decided that is certainly your prerogative.

The problem with your idea is that parsers don't actually work that way. If you look at Ripper or Parser you'll notice that there are no methods really to dump the abstract syntax tree back out as source code. Producing well formed code is relatively hard problem.

@max https://github.com/mbj/unparser

You could use route method from rails generators:
require "rails/generators"

Rails::Generators::Base.new.route(%(get "/health_check", to: "health_check#show"))

